# Matlab .Fig equivalent in R

Tags: r, matlab

I'm a user of both Matlab and R. One of the wonderful advantages in Matlab is that, one can SAVE a figure as .fig file format. This allows all users to reopen the figure anytime later, thus one can either make minor adjustments to the figure or can export the figure in other formats (jpg, tiff, eps, etc.)/resolution or can do both, if needed. Is there any option to do so in R?? Sometimes it takes 5-10 minutes to create a detailed plot and then when I need to export it in a different format or resolution (let aside minor adjustments), I have no choice other than redoing the whole process! Isn't that annoying??

Comment: there is and you should see [here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/saving.html) for details.

Comment: @Metrics I don't think the OP is referring to actually rendering the graph. You can save ggplot2 and lattice objects using `save()` just like you would any other R object, prior to rendering them, and then `load` them back in for further tweaking.

Comment: I think the canonical way in R is to save the script that produces the plot and rerun it if needed. If creating the data for plotting is very time consuming, `save` or `saveRDS` can be used to save it. AFAIK there is no figure file format that allows modifying it in R.

Comment: @joran Saving those doesn't offer advantages over simply rerunning the script or am I missing something? The whole plot has to be rendered again, anyway.

Comment: isn't this a non-issue though, since R doesn't have a GUI to tweak graphics by hand, you should always have a script that you can simply run to reproduce the original figure, no?

Comment: @joran more generally, any grid graphics can be saved (`?grid.grab`)

Comment: @Roland Depends on the script. I agree that (for base graphics) re-running the script is the way to go. But sometimes my script might have involved a fair bit of computation to get the data in the right format. We're picking nits, here, though.

Comment: well, if your computation took a long time to get the data in the right format, just save the transformed data as a `.RData` file.  Really the issue is whole long it takes to *render* the plot once all the data are exactly as they need to be.

Comment: This: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/ suggests that if you wanted to you could develop a "bundled" `.RData` + plot code object that could be stored and retrieved. Before bothering I'd really want to see the detailed use case, though.

Comment: If the plot is taking so long to make, you might look at Hadley Wickham's bigvis package on github https://github.com/hadley/bigvis

Answer (score 0):

Check help for xfig.

```
xfig starts the graphics device driver 
     for producing XFig (version 3.2) graphics.
```

Comment: @Sobala: can you give an example, please?